# Tensorflow Android library asking for READ_PHONE_STATE?

Tags: android, tensorflow

In my merged manifest, I am getting READ_PHONE_STATE permission even though I haven't added it.

In the manifest log, it shows

```
uses-permission#android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE 
IMPLIED from /home/sarbajit/Programming/Github/Pierra/DeepImageStyleTransfer/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-55:12 
reason: tensorflow.contrib.android has a targetSdkVersion < 4
```

So, the tensorflow library is asking for the permission. However, it doesn't use it anywhere( at least I don't get a prompt or anything in Android 6.0). Any specific reason behind this? And is it possible to remove the permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any specific reason behind this?

Whoever wrote whatever you are using as `tensorflow.contrib.android` screwed up and either did not put a `targetSdkVersion` in the library or set it insanely low. The official `org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.2.0` does not exhibit this behavior, though I am uncertain if that is the same library.

> And is it possible to remove the permission?

I would first focus on where you are getting `tensorflow.contrib.android` from and why it is using a preposterously low `targetSdkVersion`.

That being said, you can [use `tools:remove` to get rid of the permission](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html).

Comment: I have this library compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.2.0' in the gradle file. Not sure why the permission keeps coming. But I was able to remove it using tools:remove option. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a snippet on how to remove it? I've tried adding `<permission
android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
tools:node="remove" />` to my manifest file, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts: It is `<uses-permission>`, not `<permission>`.